# Html5 video element and .mp3 files

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio

I happened to set the .src attribute of an html video tag to a .mp3 audio URL in Google Chrome. To my surprise the UI of the video tag morphed to look like an audio tag (except for the height).

The purpose of loading the URL was just to see if it were a usable video URL.

Now, I wonder, if this some kind of standard behavior? Should I expect it to continue behave like that?

And how do I know that it was an audio file and not a video file? From what I can see i the debugger the .videoHeight and .videoWidth are 0, but I do not know if that is reliable?

Comment: mp3 is audio, mp4 is video. the `video` element is smart and will display the appropriate controls. you can either check the file extension or look at the files 'magic number' (https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e) to see what it is

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks for the tip. That might be useful for getting around a bug on Android that I am waiting for Google to fix.

Comment: This list seems to be the best: List of file signatures - Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures